# Increasing the number of reminder snooze options in MacOS

Tags: macos, calendar, reminders

This is an issue I've faced for such a long time on both macOS and iOS, though for the purpose of this question I'd like to focus on macOS as that is where, I hope, manually editing settings files might even be a possible solution to this problem.

If a *calendar* alert pops up on macOS, we're presented with some quite usable snooze options: 1 minute, 5 minutes, 15 minutes, 30 minutes, 1 hour, 2 hours, 1 day, or 1 week:

[image: Calendar snooze options]

On the flip side, if a *reminder* alert pops up on macOS, one only has the option to snooze it for 5 minutes, 1 hour, or until tomorrow, with nothing in between. This has obvious implications: if there's something you want to do in 15 minutes or 30 minutes, you don't have that option. You can only push the reminder to 5 minutes over and over, or push it a whole hour and risk not getting to it in time:

[image: Reminder snooze options]

On iOS, its even worse. If a reminder pops up, a user can only choose between "mark as completed", "remind me in 1 hour", or "remind me tomorrow" with a hard press on the iPhone 7.

I feel like Apple has decided that a reminder is for something to be done NOW (or in 5 minutes max) and doesn't want people postponing reminders in, say, 15 minute increments. If anything, it's Calendar time slots that might be marginally more immediate and fixed in time than reminders, aren't they? I think it's crazy to only have a choice between 5 minutes and a full hour to postpone our reminders, while being forced to go into the reminders app to manually change the time for each alert!

I've read through prior posts on here and other forums, skirting this topic, but there doesn't seem to be a conclusive answer.

Is there any way to manually edit the native list of reminder *postponement* duration options to at least match the calendar *snooze* options, or are we totally out of luck save for downloading software such as Snoozemaster which doesn't natively sort the problem, or having to specify a reminder snooze time via Siri (difficult in a quiet office environment)?

Answer (score 15):

Those notifications are managed by the **Notification Center App Extension** inside of *Reminders.app*: `/Applications/Reminders.app/Contents/PlugIns/com.apple.RemindersNC.appex`
and displayed by *Notification Center*. Sadly none of the information used to create the window is editable by the user.

Interestingly, there were more options when this feature was introduced in Mavericks. http://www.mactricksandtips.com/2013/11/change-the-snooze-time-of-a-reminder.html

[image]

As of macOS 12 Monterey the Reminder options are:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You may not like this answer (in fact, I don't like it), but I suspect the best option is to use a 3rd party reminders program that provides different interface to Apple's Reminder system.

Personally, I use Fantastical which provides all these options.  I disabled the Reminder app notifications and only use the ones from Fantastical.  Unfortunately, Fantastical is expensive, especially if you pop for the subscription extras.

I also use GoodTask, which is much cheaper and very highly configurable.